# In React how can I trigger a custom button's click event from a different compoennt's event handler?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I have a React app which uses [Material UI](https://v3.material-ui.com/) for it's interface. I've created a custom button component which styles the default Material UI button and also uses redux.

The `render()` function of my button component looks like this:

```
        return (
            <div className={classes.buttonWrapper}>
                <Button 
                    ref={this.props.innerRef}
                    disabled={loading || disabled}
                    onClick={this.handleClick}
                    {...other}>
                    <React.Fragment>
                        {children}
                        {this.buildLoader(loading, classes)}
                    </React.Fragment>
                </Button>
            </div>
        );
```

What I want is to be able to include this button on a page and have the UI trigger its click event by other means other than clicking on it. For example, on a login form I want a user who currently has focus on the password textbox to be able to trigger the button click by hitting the Return/Enter key.

I'm sure I need to use the concept of forwarding refs in React, but I'm fairly new to React and can't get it working. You can see on my button I've defined a `ref` set to `this.props.innerRef`. My button component (called `WaitingButton`) is exported like this:

```
const withInnerRef = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => <WaitingButton 
  innerRef={ref} {...props}
/>);

var component = withStyles(styles)(withInnerRef);

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(component);
```

I've then added this button to a form like this:

```
    <Paper>
        <TextField 
            style={{marginBottom: '8px'}}
            label="A textbox!"
            fullWidth 
            onKeyPress={(e) => { if (e.key === "Enter") this.triggerClick(); }} />
        <WaitingButton 
            ref={this.submitButton}
            variant="contained"
            color="primary"
            onClick={(e) => {
                console.log('Button clicked :)', e.target);
            }}>
            Press enter in textbox!
        </WaitingButton>
    </Paper>
```

See I've assigned the button's `ref` and in this page's constructor I've initialised the ref in the constructor using `this.submitButton = React.createRef();`

Finally the `triggerClick` looks like this:

```
    triggerClick() {
        console.log('CLICK', this.submitButton.current);
        this.submitButton.current.click();
    }
```

When I hit enter in the textbox, I can inspect the value assigned to `this.submitButton.current` and can see it is the Redux `connect` object that I've wrapped my button with. However, I also get the error `this.submitButton.current.click is not a function` so clearly the ref isn't getting forwarded all the way to the button itself.

I'm afraid I'm a bit lost so appealing for your help!

Comment: I don't know if this could help, but submitting the form upon clicking the enter key while an input has focus, is the default behavior in most browser. Your input must be inside a form element, though. You can try this out in this pen I made: https://codepen.io/giuseppedeponte/pen/ExxPpMO (no submit button here, but you should still be able to submit)

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate the idea. But I do want to specifically trigger the button's click event because it has a loading visual. The form data is posted to an API anyway so I don't want the default HTML form behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tried to reproduce your case. And I created a codesandbox for it. I think I found the problem. It seems React.forwardRef only works with prop name forwardedRef so try to rename the innerRef property to forwardedRef in your code.

```
const withInnerRef = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => <WaitingButton 
  forwardedRef={ref} {...props}
/>);
```

and also in your render() function

```js
<Button 
    ref={this.props.forwardedRef}
    disabled={loading || disabled}
    onClick={this.handleClick}
    ...
```

You can try it with my simplified codesandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/intelligent-cori-rb5ce

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time on this. I've just spent an hour trying to understand why your example doesn't work with my codebase. Just worked out that your demo uses Material UI v4.x. I'm still on v3.x. I'm guessing `withStyles` in v3 didn't pass on a forwarded ref. See here for an example which shows the forwarded ref in the console when the button is clicked. It's a `withStyles` component rather than the HTML button element - https://codesandbox.io/embed/pensive-dream-1iyfo . But yours is the correct direct answer to my question. Unfortunately I can't use it until I upgrade :(

Comment: It was a challenge for me to use forwardRef for the first time. Other than that @Devin solution is more in line with React. It is declarative and not imperative.

Answer (score 2):

Just want to ensure, what you want is: when user press `Enter` while typing on the textfield, the button will show a loading visual, right?
I think you don't have to pass ref to the button component, you could just pass state `isLoadingShown` into your `WaitingButton`

WaitingButton.js

```
 return (
        <div className={classes.buttonWrapper}>
            <Button 
                ref={this.props.innerRef}
                disabled={loading || disabled}
                onClick={this.handleClick}
                {...other}>
                <React.Fragment>
                    {children}
                    {this.props.isLoadingShown && this.buildLoader(loading, classes)}
                </React.Fragment>
            </Button>
        </div>
    );
```

Then in the form component

```
state = {
   isLoadingShown: false,
}

triggerClick() {
    this.setState({ isLoadingShown: true })
}

render(){
   ...
   <Paper>
       <TextField 
           style={{marginBottom: '8px'}}
           label="A textbox!"
           fullWidth 
           onKeyPress={(e) => { if (e.key === "Enter") this.triggerClick(); }} />
       <WaitingButton
           variant="contained"
           color="primary"
           isLoadingShown={this.state.isLoadingShown}
           onClick={(e) => {
               console.log('Button clicked :)', e.target);
           }}>
           Press enter in textbox!
       </WaitingButton>
   </Paper>
   ...
}
```

don't forget to set `isLoadingShown` to false again in `componentWillUnmount`

Comment: Thank you. While this isn't a direct answer to my question, it's actually a good suggestion. I wasn't thinking outside the box! See my response to @peter-ambruzs answer - there is a way to use `forwardedRef` but my version of Material UI is too old. But still, +1 for an alternative approach which I may have to use in my case.